# Flutter email sender doesn't send, only create email

Tags: flutter

I want to send email in background.

Im using example from  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender

```
    final Email email = Email(
    body: 'Email body',
    subject: 'Email subject',
    recipients: ['smth@gmail.com'],
    isHTML: false,
    );
    await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
```

But letter does'n sends. It only creates on screen. What should i do to send it without user's actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send email without user agreement because it is not safety (if you can do it anybody can send spam messages to other users by email). This plugin just opens default email app on device.

Comment: Is there any ways to send email without user's actions?

Comment: It is custom and not good solution (because when user try to send email, they can change address in default client). What feature do you try to realize?

Comment: i want to resend sms via email.